# Assassin Creed 3 Bug Cursor appear when use Shift+F2

Tags: technical-issues, keyboard, assassins-creed-3

I have a problem with Assassin Creed 3 when I want to check my FriendList with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, the cursor should be normal cursor (desktop cursor), and when I close it by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> again, the Desktop cursor is stuck and I have two kind of cursors, Assassin Creed 3 cursor and Desktop cursor.

How to fix this bug? It's annoying when I play, it always appears on my screen.